# Cambiar color de los puntos en Matplotlib-PYTHON 3.6

Tags: python, matplotlib, color

Tengo este ejemplo de código que genera una gráfica de puntos en python.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
n = 5000
x = np.random.randn(n)
y = np.random.randn(n)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
plt.plot(x,y,'o',markersize=2)
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna forma de colorear cada uno de estos puntos en función de un tercer parámetro?? Por ejemplo:

- variable = 0  Color verde
- variable = 1  Color naranja
- variable = 2  Color rojo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mediante `plt.scatter()` puedes especificar una secuencia de colores, que se usará para pintar cada uno de los puntos, que debes pasarle a través del parámetro `c`.

Si la "variable" adicional asociada a cada punto la tienes en otro vector numpy, por ejemplo:

```
 v = np.random.randint(0, 3, size=n)
```

entonces puedes crea una lista python con los tres colores deseados:

```
colores = ["#00cc44",  # Verde
           "#ff7700",  # Naranja
           "#ff0000"   # Rojo
          ]
```

y usar los elementos de `v` (que son enteros entre 0 y 2, ambos inclusive) como índices dentro de la lista de colores. Por ejemplo, `np.take(colores, v)` generaría una lista con el color asociado a cada uno de los puntos.

Entonces:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 5000
x = np.random.randn(n)
y = np.random.randn(n)
v = np.random.randint(0, 3, size=n)
colores = ["#00cc44",  # Verde
           "#ff7700",  # Naranja
           "#ff0000"   # Rojo
          ]

plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
plt.scatter(x, y, s=30, c=np.take(colores, v))
plt.show()
```

[image: Resultado]

Comment: Muchas gracias es justo lo que quería.

Answer (score 0):

La función **plot** acepta, entre otras, la siguiente sintáxis:

> plot(x, y, 'bo')

Donde ese 'bo', quiere decir:

> b: color azul
>
> o: caracter circulo (para representar la coordenada)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
n = 50
x1 = np.random.randn(n)
y1 = np.random.randn(n)
x2 = np.random.randn(n)
y2 = np.random.randn(n)
x3 = np.random.randn(n)
y3 = np.random.randn(n)

plt.plot(x1, y1, "or", x2, y2, "^g", x3, y3, "xr", markersize=1)

plt.show()
```

En el ejemplo, utilicé tres coordenadas x e y, y tres combinaciones de color y simbolo, siendo cada una:

> **"or"**: circulo azul.
>
> **"^g"**: flecha hacia arriba, verde.
>
> **"xr"**: x roja.